# Swft / Xcode - pod framework and dynamic framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

Recently I've read several posts about using frameworks in other frameworks by creating the so called `Umbrella Framework`. But... I have not found an answer that would get rid of my problem.

As a beginner to `iOS, Swift and Xcode` I'm working on an app that uses simple pod framework `QVRWeekView` and another one - the mighty Realm framework (to store `QVRWeekView's EvenData` objects). The problem is that I cannot import Realm to `QVRWeekView's EventData` class to be able to store them. I've already tried to import Realm as pod as well as adding dynamic Realm framework by drag and dropping to Embedded Binaries with no luck.

I'm stuck and have no idea what should I do to make it work. Do I really have to make an Umbrella Framework to be able to use Realm in `QVRWeekView` and in my files? Aren't pod frameworks supposed to work with each other?

Any help will be much appreciated! :-)

Comment: please try from this link https://medium.com/@bittudavis/how-to-create-an-umbrella-framework-in-swift-ca964d0a2345

Comment: Why you want to unlock `QVRWeekView`? Your problem does not allow to use a `subClass`?

Comment: Even if subclassed:
`class EventDataSub: EventData{...}`
I won't be able to iherit from RealmSwift (Object):
`class EventDataSub: EventData, Object{...}`
as Swift doesn't suppor multi-inheritance...
do you have any other ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I've bypassed the problem by creating a class with the same fields, import Realm and return converted array from Realm's query.